# Does C# reuse existing objects that have not been destroyed by GC?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, c#-3.0

I have an object named MyObject. It provides some bussiness operation and doesn't contain any data. In source code, I initialize it to do some operations:

```
MyObject myObj = new MyObject();
```

at other place I initialize a new one with different name:

```
MyObject BuObj = new MyObject();
```

If myObj has not been destroyed by GC then MyObject too. So when I initialize BuObj does C# reuse MyObject for BuObj instead of initialize a new one?

Comment: This almost feels like _[if a tree falls in a forest and no one is around to hear it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_a_tree_falls_in_a_forest)_...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it will create a new one. The C#/.Net GC doesn't reuse existing objects, only destroys them.

What you're talking about is called an Object Pool; if you want to make use of that concept you'll have to implment that functionality yourself, or find an existing library that does so. But "new" will still only create a new object.

Answer (score 5):

You need to differentiate between a *variable* (`myObj`) and the object that the variable's value refers to. A *variable* can never be garbage collected - only objects can.

But no, .NET won't reuse the same object: you've asked for a new one, so it will create a new one.

(There's *one* tiny corner case in terms of creating empty strings where the `new` operator happens to return a reference to an existing object, but you can mostly ignore that.)

Comment: that's right. MyObj is a variable containing the address to the object which was allocated on Heap.

Comment: @PraveenLearnsEveryday: Well, containing a reference to the object. The form of the reference may be a memory address, but logically it's just "some way of navigating to the object".

Answer (score 0):

In short, No. C# does not reuse any objects.